# fcm notification showing three times whenever change occur in database

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am currently using firebase as database and to notify the user whenever any changes occur on database i am using fcm . i have created firebase function through node.js and whenever any change occurs on database it'triggered and notification will be send to the user but instead of showing notification once its showing three times the same notification. i search a lot on internet but have not found the solution yet.
Here is the screenShot https://imgur.com/a/zNXjo 
  Any help will be appreciated.

 This is my FirebaseMessagingClass

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

/**
 * Created by HP on 04-07-2017.
 */

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingServce";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String notificationTitle = null, notificationBody = null;
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        }
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        sendNotification(notificationTitle, notificationBody);
    }
    private void sendNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FragmentTwo.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//                .setAutoCancel(true)
//                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)

//                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

//                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) //Notification icon
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)   //Automatically delete the notification
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                    .setContentText(notificationBody)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        } else
        {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                    .setContentText(notificationBody)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Ans this is my service class

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

/**
 * Created by HP on 07-09-2017.
 */

public class myInstanceService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG=FirebaseInstanceIdService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken) {

    }

}
```

Tis is my cloud function code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
// Listens for new messages added to messages/:pushId
exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/News/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

    //  Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var valueObject = event.data.val();

    if(valueObject.Image != null) {
      valueObject.Image= "Sent you a photo!";
    }

  // Create a notification
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title:valueObject.Title,
            body: valueObject.Description || valueObject.Image,
            sound: "default"
        },
    };

  //Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };


    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("pushNotifications", payload, options);
});
```

Comment: You haven't shown your cloud functions code.  Also, you haven't shown the client code that writes to the database.  These seem important to know.

Comment: I have edit the code as said by you. please have a look  and help.

Comment: You might check with `console.log("...")` in Functions code how many times the function gets executed.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot This is the screenshot of my firebase function dashboard it's showing like this https://imgur.com/a/0t9YH

Comment: @GulshanKumar It looks like the function is executed three times at once. You should make sure that there is just a single write event. You can also use other triggers (*onCreate*, *onUpdate* and *onDelete*)

Comment: Could you please tell me how to check that there is single write event. i am newbie and don't know how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Where is your code that pushes to /News?